# New ReactNative project doesnt apply full screen size view

Tags: react-native, react-native-safe-area-view

i just created a new react native project (0.73.6)
and my App.tsx is

```
 import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text, View} from 'react-native';

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    // <SafeAreaView style={{}}>
    <View style={{}}>
      <Text>Hey</Text>
    </View>
    // </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when i run the app its load like this . i big gap between top and bottom
[image]

i also added a normal app screenshot. so its easy to see the gap and what is wrong there because App.tsx just a simple code

[image]

Comment: How are you running the app? Have a play around in the online expo tool: https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=ios

Answer (score 0):

Install `react-native-safe-area-context` using `npm install react-native-safe-area-context`. Wrap your code in `<SafeAreaProvider>` and then `<SafeAreaView>`. This time, `<SafeAreaView>` is imported from `react-native-safe-area-context`. See if this works.
sample code

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View>
          <Text>Hey</Text>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```